# Having trouble with photo and div layout with padding

Tags: html, css, padding

I'm trying to replicate a website that claimed it was only made with the basic Html, CSS and JavaScript. Annoyingly I can't seem to make the images responsive and relatively the same

Can someone explain to me what I’m doing wrong? I'm using flexbox to make the site responsive but the alignments are off and I cant get them to sit next to each other with all the correct padding as well

This is my work:
https://codepen.io/Hitmonchan98/pen/PoQLRPy

This is what I want my site to look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsdxo.jpg

```
//html





<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="main-img"><img class="firstImage"src="https://www.amazingonly.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/images4-1728x1080.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h2>Discover innovative ways to decorate</h2>
      <p class="para">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia repudiandae dolore iure laudantium fugiat fuga sunt unde voluptates et, quasi exercitationem eum consectetur. Doloremque, ab?</p>
       <div class="shop">Shop Now</div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
  <div class="lower">
    <div class="dark image">
      <img class="dark-img" src="https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Download-Free-Pictures-4k.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="text2">
      <h3>About furniture</h3><p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Natus ipsa, adipisci perspiciatis debitis magni sed possimus pariatur qui exercitationem fugiat iusto error ducimus, quos quis, eius earum tempore quibusdam laboriosam!</p></p></div>
    <div class="light image">
       <img class="light-img"src="https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Download-Free-Pictures-4k.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

//css

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

/*Body*/
.firstImage,.light-img,.dark-img
{
  width: 100%;
}
.text2{
 padding: 2rem;
}
.text h2
{
 font-size:3rem;
  
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .main{
  display: flex;
}
   .text{
    padding: 1rem 3rem 3.5rem 3rem;
  }
  .lower{
    display: flex;
    align-content:center;
  }
  .text2{
    padding:0;
    width: 40%;
  }
  .dark, .light
  {
    width: 30%;
  }
  .dark-img, .light-img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
}
@media screen and (min-width: 786px) {
  
}
```

Comment: Seems like you are just asking someone to build the entire page for you.  That is not how this works.

Comment: No, just asking what I'm doing wrong, everything is in its positions just not positioning correctly

Comment: Would using grid give you  more of the sort of control you need?

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: block;` to your img elements and this should get rid of the white spacing underneath them. Images are weird in HTML since they have properties of both display inline and block, and I usually set them to block to have maximum styling control over them.